# Encapsulate the rendering of HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Can someone explain me what it means when they say:

"HTML Helpers enables to encapsulate the rendering of HTML"

Does it mean it will restrict access to the HTML attributes of an object? What if I am using CSS, jquery, Javascript, will it display my JS/jquery and CSS in page source?

Comment: In what context? HTML Helpers is meaningless without the context of what they are.

Comment: In terms of HTML elements, form controls.

Comment: In what kind of environment? HTML itself has no concept of "HTML helpers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML helpers are bits of code that will render out the HTML, instead of you writing out the HTML for each and every piece of data directly in the view.

They encapsulate it - meaning they take care of what HTML is output.

Answer (score 1):

By "encapsulating the rendering", they are referring to the encapsulation of the functionality of rendering html.

If there is a common piece of html you render often, (the rails form helpers for example), if you insert the code (or the code building functionality within a helper), each time you need to render that html (or a variant of it) , you merely call the helper method thereby keeping your code "dry" (html code in this case)